# Searching for a number in a list of ranges of numbers

Tags: performance, algorithm, search, range

Suppose there is a list of ranges of numbers, for example, 
{0,9},{14,18},{19,30}.

And I want to determine whether a number N is in the list or not.
If N=15 , the answer will be a yes because 15 is in the range {14,18}
If N=11 , the answer will be a no because 11 is not in those ranges in the list.

My question is :
Is there any efficient way to determine the answer to such a problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is the range of numbers sorted?

Comment: Each range contains just the smallest and the largest numbers.
For example, range {2,5} doesn't actually contain 2,3,4,5 but just 2 and 5.

Comment: No my question was whether this type of range is possible: {14,18} {0,9} {19,30} i.e. the input range is unsorted.

Comment: yes, such an ordering is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sort the list of ranges, then join the overlapping ranges, you may solve your problem with a binary search, which is O(log(N)), where N is the number of elements in the list.

After you sort and join the ranges, you may put your range list in an array, for example, { a, b }, { c, d } will become ( a, b, c, d ), and after the binary search you may check if your number falls between elements with an even and odd position, then your number is within the range, otherwise it's out.

Binary search is where you have a sorted array, so you can divide the array into two equal parts and compare your key value to the array value, that separates the parts, then choose upper part or lower part to divide again and again.

If you don't use binary search, and your list is unsorted, you have to look through all elements every time, which O(N) and is considered quite inefficient.

Leave a comment, if you need more detailed explanation.

Comment: Actually, ranges do not overlap with each other, meaning they are disjoint with respect with each other.

But I was also thinking about merging adjacent ranges when possible to reduce the number of ranges inside the list.

The list will dynamically change as the processor that performs this task will receive ranges of numbers from other processors
,allowing the ranges to come in arbitrary order.

I don't still understand the part where you mentioned using the binary search to check. Could you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: Binary search is O(log(N)), which is of course a subset of O(sqrt(N)), nevertheless the O(log(N)) asymptotic class is more precise here.

Comment: If the ranges are not sorted, then we are doing a O (n log n) operation to sort the ranges, where n is the number of ranges. Wouldn't this make this method worse than the naive method, which is to check each range and see if the number falls within it, which is O (n)?

Comment: @Kaushik: that depends on how often the ranges change and how often you have to check a number against those ranges. if, for example, there are 5 changes and 1 check on average, naive method is the best.

Comment: I agree. But theoretically speaking, you still should consider it when nothing is mentioned about use-cases. ;)

Comment: @Kaushik: if someone asks about finding a word in a dictionary, it's customary to assume, (s)he want to search for a few different words in a more-or-less fixed dictionary, but not the same word in a hundred of different dictionaries. Get a life, dude, instead of pointless nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

If the list of ranges dynamically changes, then the [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is the data structure you are looking for.

Comment: Many Thanks, Rafal.
I will take a look at this and hope this is what I am looking for.